# ¿Como puedo filtrar una lista recibida desde un ViewModel enviando como parámetro el ID desde una vista parcial a otra vista parcial en ASP .Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

Tengo una vista parcial llamada **_Items** en la cual muestro una lista de `Items` (Preguntas) y dentro de esta llamo a otra vista parcial llamada **_Respuestas** en la cual quiero listar las respuestas cuyo  `ItemID` del modelo Respuestas sea igual al `ItemID` del Modelo `Items`, el cual le envió por parámetro al al controlador de **_Respuestas** desde la vista parcial **_Items**.

El problema es que al pasar el modelo completo a la vista `return View(ViewModels);` me compila pero muestra todas las respuestas como se muestra en la siguiente imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando trato de filtrarlas por su `ItemID` `return View(ViewModels.Respuestas.Where(r => r.ItemID == ItemID).ToList());`  recibo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. El elemento de modelo pasado
>   al diccionario es de tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Actividades.Models.Respuesta]',
>   pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo
>   'Actividades.ViewModels.ActividadesViewModel'.

**Este es mi ViewModel:**

```
using Actividades.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Actividades.ViewModels
{
    public class ActividadesViewModel
    {
        public List<Respuesta> Respuestas { get; set; }

        public List<Actividad> Actividades { get; set; }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Mi vista parcial de _Items:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Actividades.Models.Item>


<h1>
    Evaluación
</h1>

<table class="table">


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3><b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Detalle)</b></h3>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        @Html.Action("_Respuestas", "Respuestas", new { ItemID = item.ItemID})

    }


</table>
```

**Mi vista parcial de _Respuestas:**

```
@model Actividades.ViewModels.ActividadesViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<table>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Respuestas)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="@item.ItemID" value="@item.RespuestaID" unchecked="Uncheck">  @item.Detalle
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

**Controlador de _Respuestas:**

```
public ActionResult _Respuestas(int? ItemID)

        {
            ActividadesViewModel ViewModels = new ActividadesViewModel();
            ViewModels.Actividades = db.Actividad.ToList();
            ViewModels.Items = db.Item.ToList();
           ViewModels.Respuestas = db.Respuesta.ToList();


return View(ViewModels.Respuestas.Where(r => r. ItemID == ItemID).ToList());

}
```

**Estas son las clases que componen el ViewModel:**

```
public partial class Respuesta
    {
        public int RespuestaID { get; set; }
        public string Detalle { get; set; }
        public string Realimentacion { get; set; }
        public int Puntos { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Item
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Item()
        {
            this.Respuesta = new HashSet<Respuesta>();
        }

        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string Detalle { get; set; }
        public bool Activo { get; set; } = true;
        public int ActividadID { get; set; }

        public virtual Actividad Actividad { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Respuesta> Respuesta { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: El problema pasa porque en el método estas devolviendo una lista de repuestas con `ViewModels.Respuestas.Where(r => r. ItemID == ItemID).ToList()` pero lo que deberias devolver (y lo que espera tu vista) es un objeto de tipo `ActividadesViewModel`. Adecua la respuesta tu método para que devuelva dicho objeto y se solucionará :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu Vista parcial **_Respuestas** tienes definido un Modelo del tipo **`@model Actividades.ViewModels.ActividadesViewModel`**, por lo tanto debes devolver desde la Acción `public ActionResult _Respuestas(int? ItemID)` del Controlador, un **objeto del mismo tipo**.

Modifica la Acción del Controlador, para que te devuelva el objeto correcto de la siguiente manera:

```
    public ActionResult _Respuestas(int? ItemID)
    {
        ActividadesViewModel ViewModels = new ActividadesViewModel();
        ViewModels.Actividades = db.Actividad.ToList();
        ViewModels.Items = db.Item.ToList();
        // ViewModels.Respuestas = db.Respuesta.ToList();
        ViewModels.Respuestas = db.Respuesta.Where(r => r. ItemID == ItemID).ToList();

        return View(ViewModels);
     }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rafael Acosta su respuesta soluciono mi problema y me aclaro mi error para no cometerlo nuevamente!